# AndEngine 2.0 with AVD Emulator hangs after loading scene

Tags: android, android-emulator, andengine

I'm following the tutorial shown [here](https://jimmaru.wordpress.com/2012/05/19/jimvaders-my-own-invaders-clone-thingie-tutorial/) to make my first game using AndEngine with OpenGLES 2.0. I've set my emulator up to use GPU Emulation, but when I launch my emulator and start the application, the scene appears but nothing happens; the scene has a green background, but other than that, the app appears to hang, even though LogCat registers screen taps.

What should happen is that two Text objects should move towards each other towards the center, and two seconds after that Scene appears, the app should switch to another Scene. Neither of these actions happen, however.

I'm not familiar with AndEngine so I'm not really sure what else to do from here; can anyone help?

Thanks!

[EDIT] Here's the logcat: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B3DKYyqpVX9MdDh2MDF3VF9jMlk

Comment: It's better you post your log cat here, so people can anticipate your problems

Comment: LogCat posted. Also, I noticed something in the LogCat when I read through it - it mentions "MainActivity.onPause @(Thread: 'main')". Is it possible the app is starting out paused? If so, how can I resume it?

Comment: Also, a window just popped up when I left the app running, saying: "Process system is not responding. Would you like to close it?"

Comment: I'm the author of that tutorial , I never tried running it on the emulator though
could you try downloading the whole project that I provided at the end of the tutorial then check if it works or not ?

Comment: Hi JiMMaR, I'll give that a try and let you know how it turns out.